# Start script on network connect

Tags: linux, bash, network-adapter, raspberry-pi, bash-scripting

I am trying to get a GNU/Linux Bash script to run as soon as a network connection is established on my Raspberry Pi. I tried following the instructions on several pages:

I have tried adding my script to `/etc/network/if-up.d` and running `sudo chmod ugo+x` on the file.

I have tried adding the line `post-up <path/to/script.sh>` to `/etc/network/interfaces`

I am really quite clueless here.

**More info:**

The script runs fine when manually run, here it is: http://pastebin.com/UJvt5HYU (I did remove my personal info (email addresses, passwords), but other than that, the script is unchanged. This script also uses the sendEmail program (can be found at http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/).

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show us the relevant files. Please post your script's code. Does it run OK if you run it manually? Are you using a full path or a relative one? Please always include all the relevant files in your question.

Comment: Can you make the script log to a file so that you can see what the script is trying to do, and what it fails on ? Also, have you tried putting the script into /etc/network/if-up.d but make sure it has no file extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by putting the script into `/etc/network/if-up.d/` with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` that executes a python email script, which looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=EmailOnBoot
Exec="python ~/Path/To/SendEmail.py"
Type=Application
```

If you dont have `~/.config/autostart` you can just create it, and make the `file.desktop` in it executable. 
It executes after everything else including network connection (WiFi in my case).